# Как совместить long polling и schedule?

Tags: python, long-poll, telebot

Есть телеграм бот, реализованный через `pytelegrambotapi`. Сделал таймер, который должен выполнять раз в n-секунд, но оно не отрабатывает почему-то.

```
def low_level_balance_timer():
    print('ax')
    users = getAllUsers()
    for user in users:
        pass
        #check balance
        # if balance low 
        # notify
    time.sleep(60)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(low_level_balance_timer)

def main_loop():
    bot.polling(True)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_loop()
```

Comment: Ну так лонгполлинг работает, телеграм бот пашет)

Comment: Угу, я написал, а потом полез в исходники https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py, после понял, что фигню написал :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `schedule.run_pending()` и `bot.polling(True)` работают в одном потоке и когда вы вызываете `time.sleep(...)`, то текущий поток засыпает.

Поэтому, нужно разграничить их работу, создав второй поток, например так:

```
from threading import Thread


def low_level_balance_timer():
    print('ax')
    users = getAllUsers()
    for user in users:
        pass
        #check balance
        # if balance low 
        # notify
    time.sleep(60)


def do_schedule():
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(low_level_balance_timer)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def main_loop():
    thread = Thread(target=do_schedule)
    thread.start()

    bot.polling(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_loop()
```

Comment: Изумительно!!!!!!!