# Отправка сообщений пользователю в определённое время. TelegramBot

Tags: python, telebot

Имеется TelegramBot, который должен отправлять сообщение в выбранное пользователем время. Я пробовал реализовать это с помощью shedule, но столкнулся с проблемой, бесконечный цикл по проверки времени мешает работе бота. Может я что-то делаю не так или же есть другие способы проверки времени?

Вот так я пытался сделать.

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(check_timetable_change())
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: А так, у вас тут два цикла в одном потоке. Первый  -- для `schedule`, второй для бота. Соответственно, один из них нужно отправить в отдельный поток через `threading.Thread`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1087061/201445

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно получилось!

Comment: Сами оформите как ответ с вашим кодом :)